# H264 decoder source code

Tags: h.264, decoder

I am looking for h264 decoder C/C++ source code with RTP packetization support.
My embedded device is sending 640x480 encoded h264 RTP packet. I would like to make a Windows XP/Vista based video streaming display.

Where can I find the source code to this?

Comment: take a look at [gstreamer](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org)

Answer (score 5):

You should take a look at the [h.264 reference implementation](http://iphome.hhi.de/suehring/tml/). RTP packetization is supported, and there are both an encoder and a decoder.

Answer (score 1):

Videolan contains an implementation of [h264 encoder](http://www.videolan.org/developers/x264.html)    (sorry - It uses ffmpeg to play back h264)

It's under the GPL and is a clean room implementation from the specs. Depending on your country there might also be patents on the decoder.

Comment: Sorry? The OP asks about a player and videolan contains player source

Comment: If is FFMpeg that contains the H.264 decoder. x264 is only an encoding library.